# How do I calculate the total busy time between several start-end dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I have a table like this:

[image]

```
Event   Start               End
1       1/1/2015 10:00      1/1/2015 10:05
2       1/1/2015 10:02      1/1/2015 10:07
3       1/1/2015 10:10      1/1/2015 10:12
```

I want to calculate the number of busy minutes per day.

In my example I was busy between 10:00 and 10:07  and between 10:10 and 10:12 so 9 minutes.
Whereas if you summup all the "minutes" you end up with 12 but it is wrong because you calculate twice the time "10:02;10:03;10:04;10:05" !!!

How can I address this ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be quite easy:

```
Event   Start               End              Value
1       01/01/2015 10:00    01/01/2015 10:05    00:05:00   <- =C2-B2
2       01/01/2015 10:02    01/01/2015 10:07    00:05:00   <- =C3-B3
3       01/01/2015 10:10    01/01/2015 10:12    00:02:00   <- etc.
                                       Total:   00:12:00   <- =SUM(D2:D4)
```

Comment: Hello your calculation is wrong since you addup 12 and the result is 9 because even if I do 2 diffent tasks betwwen 10:07 and 10:10, there are only 3 minutes in this timespace and not 5

Comment: I didn't see that when I was posting result. I think there is no easy way to find overlapping time spans;/ Maybe you should think about VBA